# How to search data's for cross year table Structure

Tags: sql-server, database

Currently My table structure is based on the year format like (Table_2016,Table_2017,Table_2018), If i need to get the data from (2016 to 2018) only way is to union all the year table ? or else is there any way to get the values.

Comment: You should have considered table partitioning on year.

Comment: That is not a good design at all. If you have a table for every year you will have to use a union like that to get them all back as a single table again. The worst part is that all of your queries have to change every year to include the new table. This is just awful.

Comment: Any better way solve this is out?

Comment: The way to "solve" it would be to have one table, and have a column that denotes the year.

Comment: So as of my understanding create a table with all year data and have a column that denotes the year, based on year column set the Create Partition Range Function iam i right?

Comment: Yeah there is no easy button here. To be honest unless you have a lot of data table partitioning is not required. Most times I see this type of design partitioning is way overkill. It just got designed poorly due to a lack of understanding data. Here is one of the best articles on partitioning. https://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/ Particularly see the link about deciding if you should use partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a lot of the comments, the database architecture is not very good. As @PSK mentioned you could have table partitioning, but I do think you need Enterprise Edition for partitioning. Or you could have a DateAdded on the table instead. But I like a challenge. So please Stored Procedure I created below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectFrom_Table_Year
(
    @stringValue NVARCHAR(4000)
)

AS


SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(256),
        @sql NVARCHAR(4000),
        @querystring NVARCHAR(4000) = ''


--split the input variable
SELECT  Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
INTO #tables
FROM  
(
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@stringValue, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  

) AS A 
 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)



--concatenate the sql query  
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @tableName = Data
    FROM #tables 

    SET @querystring = @querystring + 'SELECT * FROM ' +  @tableName + ' UNION ALL '

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables) = 1
    BEGIN 
        SET @sql =  LEFT(@querystring, ABS(LEN(@querystring + ',') - 12))
    END    

    DELETE #tables WHERE Data = @tableName
END

-- execute the sql query
EXECUTE (@sql) 
DROP TABLE #tables
```

Then Execute Your Procedure as below

```
EXECUTE SelectFrom_Table_Year 'Table_2016,Table_2017'
```

Comment: This kinda sorta works but now instead of changing every query you have to change ever procedure call each year to pass in the new table name.

Comment: I Agreed this works but each of my year table contains more than 10 millions of records, If I use "union all " Is this will cause any performance issue?

Comment: @user2302158 Whats the execution time between the Stored Procedure and the UNION ALL you did? Also how else are you going to retrieve your datasets without the UNION. Yes there are other ways but to be honest I would need to see the Execution Plans to see the best solution.

Comment: find the Execution plan after  running the Store procedure https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhtDs.png

Comment: @user2302158 what was your execution time? As well can you show me Query 11 of the execution plan. Thats where it will selecting from your tables.

Comment: The execution time took around 10 min, in the below link you can find the entire execution plan    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgOPV.png

Comment: Not ideal that a query takes 10 minutes. If you run the Select statement with all the UNIONS not using the Stored Procedure, whats the execution time then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168335/discussion-between-user2302158-and-mvisser).

Answer (score 0):

> The only way is to union all the year table?

Yes, there is no magic operator that gets rows from different tables without using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Fetching data from different tables and displaying it together is not simple, data types order must match (or implicitly converted) for all columns and the SQL engine does not magically know that they represent the same entity.

What happens when you want just a subset of columns, when you want an expression that applies to one or several columns or when you want to join to other tables? You will have to write the same expression again and again for every table that holds the data, just because it is split by year.

This is *usually* a bad design and can be fixed by one of the following:

- Merging all data in one table, with year as column. Correctly handling DML and indexes will be critical when manipulating a big amount of rows.
- Using a partitioned table. Will have to create filegroups with files in different hard drives (optional but recommended), a partition function, a partition scheme and recreate your table with this partition scheme.

Partitioned tables is an advanced feature and it won't be necessary in most cases. We hold tables with more than 1.5 billion rows and they aren't partitioned (but we never do `SELECT *` !).

Comment: Yes, I agreed the design got messed up due to my less experience in Database Design, It would be great for me,that can you  give me outline idea for year wise Database Design